# C++ Active Object

Tags: c++, boost, active-objects

come across this excellent ActiveObject example in http://www.paulbridger.com/active_object/

I tried, but get only the following output:

```
Dispatching...
Waiting for results...
```

Wondering why waiting for results? Do I need to do anything in the Servant::doSomeWork()?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do with with the standard.

If you have c++0x (try -std=c++0x compiler flag or check your man file).

```
int main()
{
     auto future_int=std::async(std::launch::async, []()->int{
         //whatever you want in here
         return do_work(); //or whatever you need to do
     });
     //do other stuff
     std::cout << future_int.get() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for some samples of thread-safe object that do some works (e.g. an async loop socket listener) and at the same time reflects some statuses to the main loop.